# Heightmap in Shader not working

Tags: hlsl, heightmap

I'm trying to implement GPU-based geometry clipmapping and have problems to apply a simple heightmap to my terrain. For the heightmap I use a simple texture with the surface format "single". I've taken the texture from [Catalinz's XNA blog](http://www.catalinzima.com/tutorials/4-uses-of-vtf/terrain-rendering-using-heightmaps/).

What I'm trying to do is just getting the single float value from the texture at the vertex world coordinate and apply the value to the Y-Value of the Vertex. I'm applying the heightmap through the shader, because there is no fixed grid in-code it could be applied on. What I've tried so far was using the `tex2Dlod` function, but there seems to be no output or an output of 0. The Direct X vertex shader's code looks like this:

```
float4 worldPos = mul(float4(pos.x,0.0f,pos.y, 1.0f), worldMatrix);
float elevation = tex2Dlod(HeightmapSampler, float4(worldPos.x, worldPos.z,0,0));
worldPos.y = elevation * 128;
```

Where `HeightmapSampler` is a point-mirror sampler of the heightmap texture. Here is the output, I actually get no elevation:

[image: Screenshot]

And here's the heightmap I'm using:

[image: Heightmap]

Comment: You need to provide less code, and more details. What have you tried so far? What isn't working exactly? If you want to get an answer, try to ask a good question, check the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) for infos.

Comment: I've updated my question to be more precise.

Comment: is this a vertex or fragment shader (whatever they are called in directx)?  Can you post a screen-shot of what you are getting, and what you are expecting to get?

Comment: I expect at least some elevation characteristics. The camera is at height 40 and the maximum elevation is by 128, so I shall see something... The center of the grid is in the center of the window.

Comment: Thank you for implementing the pictures... I wasn't able to do it because of my reputation level <10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the resolution of your terrain mesh?  You're sampling the texture directly with the worldPos x & z vals: if you have a vertex every 1 unit, you'd get the same texture value each time as it's only the fractional part that's used.
See if dividing the vals has any difference, e.g.:

```
float elevation = tex2Dlod(HeightmapSampler, float4(worldPos.x*0.001, worldPos.z*0.001,0,0));
```

Comment: I'd never thought of Texture dimensions in texels... I'll try it out.